Quantum-logic tag request
I wanted to ask a question about Foulis&Randall manuals of operations, e.g., see https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0008019, but couldn't find any appropriate tag, at least none that seemed appropriate to me.
[quantum-logic] would seem to do the trick, and maybe something along the lines of [...operational...] and/or [...constructive...]. arXiv has plenty of stuff along all these lines, so I'd guess these types of tags might be of general interest.

Note that tag cannot exist without questions. So someone must at least post a question on the main site with the most related tag before anyone else can retag with newly created tags. Or otherwise find existing questions that worth these new tags and mention them here.

Possibly helpful: there are almost 300 questions tagged [quantum-mechanics] with "logic" written in the post. A superficial look at these questions suggests most posts also have [quantum-information] and/or [probability] as tags.

Note also the existence of [quantumcomputing.se].
